# Configure GSA to search Google Drive and Sites?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-search-appliance

Is there a document or article describing how to configure the GSA to search our corporate Google Drives, and Google Sites? I could not find any.

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write your own connector or use a 3rd party connector.  Although there used to be an integration module, that has been depcrecated.